# how to display new activity over another activity?

Tags: android

i have an activity that displays  two buttons , on click of call button i want to show another activity as shown in image.

[image: how to show this kind of layout]

Please help .How to achieve this

Comment: A new activity is not required for this purpose. YOu can use popupwindow or Dialog with Bottom  Gravity for this purpose.

Comment: can you please elaborate the process? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to have a custom layout which you add to each activity with a viewgroup as such:

```
private View view;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
          view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,
            null);
       parent.addView(view);
```

Then you just need to implement your listeners and whatnot further down :)

Comment: how to hide it once user clicks on button on this added layout?

Comment: never tried it but guess you can just call parent.removeView(view);

Answer (score 0):

You need to create xml file of these two buttons and add that new xml into old one by using Layout Inflator. for e.g
1) your new xml

```
LayoutInflator buttons = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.buttons,
                    currentxml, false);
```

2) your old xml parent referenced through id -->

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelatveLayout) findViewById(R.id.oldxml);
```

3) now add..

```
 relativeLayout.addView(buttons);
```

Comment: please mention here what is buttons and oldxml

Comment: buttons is the xml file new overlay containing two buttons..
and oldxml is your current xml id.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Pop up By Adding this in your function. Popuser is a `xml` file which you want to inflate.

```
public void popupshow(){
        try{
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)SRSDMain.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        int width=display.getWidth()/2;
        int height=display.getHeight()/2;

        View pop=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupuser,null,false);
        pop.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        height=pop.getMeasuredHeight();
        width=pop.getMeasuredWidth()+50;
        pu=new PopupWindow(pop,width,height,true);

        pu.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.ll3),Gravity.CENTER,1,1);

        Button btn=(Button)pu.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(new   LightingColorFilter(0xFF505450,0xFF101010));
        btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        btn.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                //anything you want to do
                pu.dismiss();

            }
        });


    }
    catch(Exception ex){
//Catch The Exception
            }
        }
    }
```